# Codeigniter Modify POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use one view for adding/editing DB data:

```
<input name="blah" id="blah" value="<? set_selected('blah')?> />
```

In my controller for edit I do this:

```
$_POST['blah'] = 'DB value';
$this->load->view('...');
```

But the input field is blank. I want the inputs to be prepopulated for my edit case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI Views can take a data array as the second parameter as others have mentioned.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

I don't like the idea of setting the $_POST array and then passing that as your data array.  $_POST should just be used for values passed from the UI form.  Since you would have to manually set your $_POST array anyways, you might as well use a separate array object.  I would create an array with all your set values.  i.e. array('blah' => $dbvalue); and pass that instead of a pre-populated $_POST array.

Secondly, your example code uses 'set_selected()'.   The function is 'set_select()' and is meant for a option tag.  So there are two issues with that line of code.  It needs to either be

```
 <input .... value="set_value('blah')" />
```

or

```
 <option ....value="v1" "set_select('blah', 'v1')">
```

Comment: Yes, a typo. I do wish CRUD could be less verbose in web frameworks.

Comment: For simple sites, yes, CRUD would be nice if it was less verbose.  I did a combination of creating my own CI Model class in conjunction with some Reflection to make it easier and less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass $_POST to view, the posted data should pass from the controller to the view in the second parameter of the view loading function. 
try this

```
   $this->load->view('content', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you pass to the view get turned into an actual variable. So your code would be.

```html
<input name="blah" id="blah" value="<?php echo $blah; ?> />
```

```php
$_POST['blah'] = 'DB value';
$this->load->view('...', $_POST);
```